# Add a contact to two gmail sources programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, google-contacts-api, contactscontract

I have two gmail accounts, (abc@gmail.com and xyz@gmail.com) synced with my Android. How can I add a contact that should be synced to both the accounts?

Using below mentioned code I am able to add contacts to only one gmail account.

```
private void addContact() {
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google") 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "abc@gmail.com") 
        .build()); 

// first and last names 
op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) 
        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Second Name") 
        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "First Name") 
        .build()); 

op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "18000000001")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
        .build());

op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "abc@xyz.com")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
        .build());

try{ 
    ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list); 
}catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}}
```

Comment: This may be possible but I think you'll have to use the webservices of the Google API and not the client library. In that case you can try to log-in and consent to the necessary permissions to sync/add the contacts you want onto other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `raw_contact` that gets synchronized to 2 accounts automatically. You just need to add the same contact twice to the two accounts.
There is no other way in android.